# HQL query trouble

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I hava a java app, with 2 objects: User.java and Review.java.

Each User can have many Reviews.

Review object has a User object on it (eg: review.getUser())

I need an hql query that will get all Users that have no Reviews. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from User u where not exists (from Review r where r.user = u)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
from User u where u.reviews is empty
```

assuming your User class has a collection of reviews, of course...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your tables and the columns in these tables, but anyway you should have a query like the following:

```
select *
from User 
where not exists (select Review where Review.userId = User.id )
```

Comment: He is asking for HQL, not SQL. Thought "not exists" is the right direction.